# How to move an object in a heart shape pattern in javascript?

Tags: mathematics, javascript

How can I move an object in a heart shaped pattern? I have a move(x, y) function that I can use to move the object, but how to I make a function that will move the object in a heart shaped pattern, with something like a setInterval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a mathematical equation that looks best to you on your own. A good starting point would be here: [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html)

As far as implementing it, here is some sample code I drew up that models a cardioid (relatively heart-shaped, though I'm sure you can find something better). The equation is : `r = a + a * sin(angle)` where the angle is in radians and a is the amplitude. It's equation is polar (you get the radius from the angle), so I do a little conversion to get x and y coords from it (sorry, this was maybe a bad example to pick :p ).

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var arr = [];

var center = {x: 100, y: 50};

var start = 0;
var stop = Math.PI * 2; //radians

var resolution = 60; //how many points to connect
var step = stop/resolution; //angle increment per point

ctx.beginPath();
for(var i = 0; i < resolution+1; i++) {
  var angle = step * i;
  var r = 50 + 50 * Math.sin(angle);
  var point = {
    x: center.x + r * Math.cos(angle),
    y: center.y + r * Math.sin(angle)
  }
  if(i !== 0) ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y); //connecting points
  else ctx.moveTo(point.x, point.y); //starting point
  arr.push(point); //create an array of points
}

ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Anyway, now you can send points.x and points.y to your move function each frame by using that array `arr`. Let me know if you have any questions.

**Quick Update:**

Ok, I was thinking about this again and realized that my quick method for drawing out a cardioid is not the most optimal method for you to actually update your object's position... so I made another short example - this time I made a cardioid function so each frame you update the position by calling this function (instead of getting the next element in an array). I used [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) because it's more awesome than setInterval - but that's a separate topic. Anyway, the code is heavily commented, so take a read and let me know if I should explain anything more.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    var center = {x: 100, y: 35};

    var start = 0;
    var stop = Math.PI * 2; //360 degrees in radians

    var player = { x: 0, y: 0, r: 5 };

    function cardioid(time) { // time range is 0 to 1
        var angle = (stop - start) * time; //get angle based on time
        var r = 50 + 50 * Math.sin(angle); // The cardioid equation with amplitude of 50
        var point = { //convert from the polar equation to x and y coords.
            x: center.x + r * Math.cos(angle),
            y: center.y + r * Math.sin(angle)
        }
        return point;
    }

    const TOTALTIME = 2; //seconds
    var timer = 0;

    var last = 0;
    function main(ms) { //this is an example loop
        requestAnimationFrame(main);

        const t = ms / 1000;
        dt = t - last; // time between last frame and this frame (delta time)
        last = t;

        timer += dt; // add to the timer

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height); //clear canvas
        
        //update player position
        if(timer <= TOTALTIME) {
            var position = cardioid(timer/TOTALTIME); //force the range to be from 1 to 0 even though the totaltime is > 1
            player.x = position.x;
            player.y = position.y;
        } else {
            timer = 0; //reset
        }
        //draw

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, player.r, 0, 2*Math.PI); //made player a circle
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
        ctx.fill();
}
requestAnimationFrame(main);
```

```html
<canvas id="c" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```